# mod_ping ( XMPP ping of ejabberd ) does NOT work

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

We are using ejabberd-16.01-linux-x86_64 and mod_ping on easy cluster several Linux server.

However, we cannot find XMPP ping packets from our producyiotn XMPP server when we use Packet Capture tool near a XMPP Client. 
On the other hand, we find XMPP ping packet form our Staging XMPP server.

We guess that each production XMPP server always are connected from many clients (over 100000 client ) and `mod_ping` cannot ping in interval period (120sec).
On the other hand, staging XMPP server has less than 10 client and can ping.

This our hypothesis is correct?
If you think another course, please let us know.

*Our configuration of mod_ping :

```
mod_ping:
     send_pings: true
     ping_interval: 120
     ping_ack_timeout: 60
     timeout_action: none
```

Thank you.

Comment: Compared to your connected client in both environment. I would suggest to increase ping_interval from 120 seconds to something more than 300 and it also depends upon ur client network too like having an issue with cellular. check this for further detail https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/376.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!   Both clients are on same condition.  So, we will test to increase the interval.